# Windows Azure worker role create report at specific TimeZoneInfo

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a worker role in Azure that needs to create specific reports at specific hour (using user timezoneinfo).

As we know, azure worker and web roles run on UTC time right? Well, my users are located in different locations around the world.

Users have a custom form app where they can select the timezone and the hour when they want to receive the report.

For example: an user from Russia will select his own TimeZoneInfo based on his location, one from France will select his own, and another from US wills select his own time zone based on location.

There is a service bus queue that will receive the messages but the messages will be delivered at specific time using `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` property. That means the message will show in the queue at the specified DateTime by the `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` property.

How can I set the value of this property so the message will show in the queue based on the time where users are located so they will get the reports in time?

Comment: Can you not convert the local time to UTC in the form app and send it to Azure?

Answer (score 0):

This will be in your app tier, as you'll need to translate a user's timezone preference into UTC prior to placing the message on the queue.